# Flex resourceManager working perfect in one file and not at all in another

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, localization, resourcemanager

I'm trying to use resourceManager in Flex for some localization. I'm having a strange problem where it works fine in the first file that I tried it in, but in the second it won't even compile.

Both files have

```
import mx.resources.ResourceBundle;
```

at the top and

```
[ResourceBundle("Hurley")]
```

above the class definition. The first one compiles fine, and pulls the text from the resources  correctly at runtime.

The second file (which is in the same project but a different folder), will not compile, and every mention of resourceManager gives an error of "1120: Access of undefined property resourceManager."

For the two different uses:

In the file that works:

```
public function SeasonsComboBox() {
    this.labelFunction = function(obj:Object):String {
        return resourceManager.getString('Hurley','Season_word') + " " + obj.number;
    };
}
```

And the file that doesn't work:

```
public function getCarousels(seriesId:String, callback:Function):void {
    [...]
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("getCarouselsFailure", function():void {
            Alert.show(resourceManager.getString('Hurley','CarouselsFailure_text'), "Error", Alert.OK);
        });
    [...]
    }
```

I can't think of anything different I did in either file.

**Edit, Solved:**

resourceManager is defined in all UIComponent subclasses. The file that worked imported ComboBox. The files that didn't don't. In those files, I can make it work by calling:

```
ResourceManager.getInstance()
```

More information here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/resources/IResourceManager.html

Comment: Does one class extend something that has access to the resourceManager, while the other does not?  Did you define resourceManager in the second class?  With the short code snippets you've shown it's tough to tell.

Comment: Neither file extends anything that deals with resourceManager. I didn't explicitly define resouceManager in either file, ResourceBundle does that already, as per the example [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_4.html). I didn't post full code because there is tons of it, and I don't think most of it is relevant.

Comment: Nevermind, you were right. One class imports ComboBox, which, as a UIComponent, already has a resourceManager.

Comment: I posted that as a formal answer then.  Although importing a ComboBox will not give you access to ResourceManager.  Extending it will.

Comment: Right, yeah, I meant to say extend, not import. Thanks. Also, I was going to post a self-answer but couldn't because I am a new account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you can't access the reourceManager property, is because it is probably not defined.

It is defined in UIComponent, so any class that extends a UIComponent that will have it defined.  But, otherwise you have to define it yourself.

You can do so using something like this:

```
public var resourceManager:ResourceManager = ResourceManager.getInstance();
```

Comment: That should be resourceManager:IResourceManager actually, since that is the type of the actual instance that gets returned.

Comment: @user1532702 Good point.  ResourceManager should implement IResourceManager, so either will work.  Unless you plan on implementing your own resourceManager as a replacement for the one included in Flex, it probably doesn't matter.